# How can I call a PHP file using a database field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building an e-commerce site using WooCommerce and want to be able to call a specific PHP file on each product page from the database entry attached to the product.

Basically, I call the database entry which contains my desired PHP file URL with this code:

```
<?php echo $product->get_attribute( 'Origin' );?>
```

'Origin' is the database field, it outputs my file url, `/assets/test.php` - I'm guessing that to call the PHP file and make it run on the page I need to combine the above call, to get the url, with the php include call... the problem is, whatever I try, it won't work.

If anyone could shed any light on this, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: What do you mean "call"? Link to via HREF? Load in via `require`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean include, like: <?php include 'header.php'; ?> - if that make sense?

Comment: This is just bad design .. calling random PHP files without a properly defined interface is madness. Please stick to the OOP / modular design guidelines, for your own benefit.

Comment: ^^^^ What does that mean - in plain English? I'm not being rude, I just don't really understand what you mean?

Comment: Having references to code file paths in your database is a really bad idea, that's what's meant. It turns into a completely unmaintainable mess almost immediately. The database should not be concerned about your program's internal structure. You should have a method in your application to load the correct class or file instead, providing at least a small degree of de-coupling between data and program.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that tadman - the file I wanted to reference was just to populate a small section of the product page, if it's a bad idea I won't do it - I'll create the layout I wanted in the main page template and populate it bit by bit with fields from the database. I thought just calling a single file would save me adding extra fields to the database - many thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your problem statement, you want to include the file which is returned by Origin field.
So try this :

```
<?php 

$url = $product->get_attribute( 'Origin' );
// check whether url is empty or not and It's valid file or not
if(!empty($url) && is_file($url)){
    require_once($url);
}

?>
```

Hope, it should work for you.

Comment: Many thanks for your help - your code looks great but for some reason, it didn't work for me - I think this is something to do with WooCommerce and not your code.  I've decided, on advice from others, not to call a php file - I'm sure your code will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include($product->get_attribute('Origin')); ?>`

This, however, is not safe.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work - many thanks for your advise though! After advise from others, I've decided not to call a file from the database.